# How to use a session of PHP local server from Vue CLI local server

Tags: php, vue.js, session, localserver

I have a PHP legacy system that I want to convert to a Vue SPA application.
At first, for backward compatibility, I'm going to use the PHP sessions for authorization as the Vue app and the PHP code going to be on the same server.

The problem is when I developing locally the Vue-CLI creates a local server which creates problems.

Vue CLI server: http://localhost:8081/
Php server: http://localhost:8090/

1. CORS - can be solved by allowing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.
2. I can't use the PHP sessions.

Is there a way to overcome it and use Vue CLI hot reload while still get PHP sessions from the local PHP server?

Comment: Is your vue app talking to PHP entirely using cross-origin Ajax? If so then the Vue app won't pass any session token to PHP, so PHP can't keep track of the requests like that. You need to pass some sort of auth token explicitly in the Ajax request. Also consider making the PHP side stateless. Vue should manage state. SPA is a fundamentally different concept from a traditional web app. You can't usually just bolt it onto the front of an existing server side implementation. Which I think is something you're slowly discovering right now.

Comment: I understand it's not optimal but this is the case right now.
If the Vue app (index.html + assets) will be on the same server as the PHP so there is no cross-origin problem and also no PHP session management problem.

I'm talking about local development using Vue-CLI (hot reload) which creates another server locally and causes these problems. 
Can I overcome them in some way? @Adyson

Comment: I understand the scenario. You can't overcome it while sticking with the session based model on the server (because session cookies aren't passed outside the site origin). You'll need a hybrid system, at least, where the PHP has a bit of an API which can just return data on-demand for any given (authenticated) request, rather than trying to track state and/or authentication through the session.